# how Altlr4 to choose alternative rules when there is ambiguity？

Tags: antlr4

I'm drafting a grammar file for a pretty much 'unstructured' text output， something like:

```
grammar Output;

rules      : (msgline|textline)* EOF;
msgline    : MSG ' '* TEXT+ NL;
textline:(TEXT+ NL)|NL;

MSG:'IEF236I';
NL      : ('\r' '\n'? | '\n');
TEXT:~[\r\n]+;
WS      : (' '|'\t')+ -> skip;
```

Namely, I want to make lines started with `IEF236I` as a messageline, all other lines as plain text.

But I found this g4 is not working as expected,  the `msgline` is always identified as a `textline`.

for example the output file looks like:

```
...
 00.21.44 JOB00167  $HASP395 TCLMVS   ENDED
0------ JES2 JOB STATISTICS ------
 IEF236I JES2 ALLOCATED TO SYSIN
...
```

And then the line of `" IEF236I JES2 ALLOCATED TO SYSIN"` is treated as textline.

my question is， how to fix the g4 to make the line of IEF236I mark as a `msgline`?

Answer (score 0):

ANTLR's lexer tries to consume as much characters as possible. So your `TEXT` rule is too greedy, causing a `MSG` token to never be created. You need to make it less greedy. You can do that by *not* letting it match white spaces. An example:

```
grammar Output;

rules    : (line (NL+ line)* NL*)? EOF;
line     : msgline | textline;
msgline  : MSG line_unit+;
textline : line_unit+;
line_unit : WORD | MSG | WS;

MSG  : 'IEF236I';
NL   : ('\r' '\n'? | '\n');
WORD : ~[ \t\r\n]+;
WS   : (' '|'\t')+;
```

Now the lexer can match the input `"IEF236I"` both as a `MSG`- and `WORD` token, but since `MSG` is defined before the `WORD` token, it chooses the one defined first (`MSG`) and things will go as expected.

Comment: Thanks Bart! Sounds reasonable, I will have a try base on your comment.